# запись и извлечение 55 миллиардов записей

Tags: база-данных

Необходимо сделать прегенерацию порядка 55 миллиардов хешей (для честного provably fair)

Помогите с выбором БД ,чтобы все это достаточно быстро туда сложить и извлечение не занимало более 10-30 секунд.

Comment: Redis или что-то другое in-memory.

Comment: @Suvitruf сколько примерно места и памяти требовать будет?

Comment: 55*10e9 / 30 секунд / 2 Гигагерца = 0.91 - то есть, по одной записи на такт!!!

Comment: посчитаем, сколько памяти под это нужно. Так как обычно хеш занимает как минимум 16 байт (есть и подлиннее и покороче, но нам для оценки), то памяти только под хеши нужно около 880 гигабайт. То есть, почти терабайт оперативки. Вам точно нужно 55 миллиардов записей?

Comment: Сосед по палате предлагает mongodb, за счет (веб)скалирования, выдержит и не такие нагрузки.

Comment: не нужно тулить монгу куда попало. Тут человек упрется в законы физики. Предлагаю посчитать, сколько нужно ширины канала для этого. Скорее всего, автору и близко не нужно такого. А скорее всего он либо просто описАлся или забыл карандаш и листик дома.